# ASP.Net MVC 3 EditorFor CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, checkboxlist, editorfor

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application using Entity Framework 4.1. I am having trouble displaying a CheckBoxList. Let me explain.

I have two ViewModel's

```
public class ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties
{
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SpecialtyList { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelCheckBox
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller, I populate my ViewModels

```
        IList<RelationshipGradeSub> gradeSubSpecialties = GetSubSpecialtiesForGrade(firstShiftGrade.gradeID);

        ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties viewModel = new ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties();

        var checkBoxList = new List<ViewModelCheckBox>();

        foreach (var item in gradeSubSpecialties)
        {
            ViewModelCheckBox chkBox = new ViewModelCheckBox { Id = item.subID.ToString(), Name = item.ListSubSpecialty.description, Checked = false, Specialty=item.ListSubSpecialty.ListItemParent.description };
            checkBoxList.Add(chkBox);
        }

        viewModel.SpecialtyList = checkBoxList;

        return View(viewModel);
```

I also have a partial view which is used as an EditorTemplate to display my checkboxes

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)        
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, Model.Name)<br />
```

Then in my View I try to filter through Model.Specialty and categorise the items into three checkboxlists based on their Specialty, ie:

```
@foreach (var sub in Model.SpecialtyList)
{
if (sub.Specialty.Equals("Medicine"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpecialtyList)
}
else if (sub.Specialty.Equals("Surgery"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpecialtyList)
}
else if (sub.Specialty.Equals("Pathology"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpecialtyList)
}

}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working at all, what this gives me is nothing in the 1st or 2nd checkboxlist, and then all list items in the 3rd checkboxlist. Basically what I am trying to achieve is something like this

[image]

Could someone please give me some pointers to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: debug and watch the Model.SpecialtyList items 0 and 1 index element

Comment: Have you tried using this: `@Html.EditorFor(m => sub)`?

Comment: So what are you actually getting then?

Comment: what doyou mean sub. i do it but result editor style ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your EditorTemplate for displaying a checkbox is for type `ViewModelCheckBox`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)        
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, Model.Name)<br />
```

In that case, you're sending in `List<ViewModelCheckBox>` when using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpecialtyList)`, but what you should send in is ViewModelCheckBox:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => sub)
```

I hope I understood you correctly.